# What sort of torque does my motor need?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, robotics

I have a cylinder that's 14 inches in diameter, 32 inches tall, and I will be connecting a motor to the center point at the end of the cylinder via a driveshaft that runs the length of the cylinder. You can assume the weight is evenly distributed throughout the cylinder.

The total weight is around 30lbs. For context, I'm creating a golf bag that holds all your clubs and rotates. The golf bag will also shoot out your clubs, so the rotation needs to be accurate so that the golf club can line up with an actuator I have.

I'm looking to understand the best motor that has enough torque and can be consistently accurate.

Also, does the angle of the golf bag matter?

I'm currently using a Nema 23 CNC Stepper Motor ([https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00PNEPW4C](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00PNEPW4C)) but am finding the motor stutters under the load of the bag (even without any golf clubs).

Images are below and any help on which motor to use/how much torque I need is appreciated. Any questions, let me know. Thanks!

Images:
https://ibb.co/XzRf6K4
https://ibb.co/MRHK3MW

Comment: Bearing? Consider a lazy susan.

Comment: To make it turn at all, the friction is more important than the mass of what you're turning. To make it respond quickly, you would also need to some kind of timing spec to calculate the torque needed to make it respond quickly.